# Cypress + Vue 3 + Vite - Custom commands invoked before page re-renders

Tags: vue.js, cypress, vite

I've recently converted a project to Vite and Vitest from vue-cli and Jest. The last part is to go through my Cypress tests and make sure they're all working, too.

I'm having trouble with one suite. To try to simplify what's happening, for various reasons this page relies on some data that's injected on into the page by the server, and there's a function that runs that reads that data and internalises it in my Vue component.

I've provided that function to the window, and I run a function in Cypress that lets me mock that injected data once the page has loaded.

All that is fine, but reading that data causes Vue to re-render the page. This particular test updates a `<select>`, which in turn changes a prefix applied to a text input. It seems as though this is happening too slowly for Cypress. Cypress seems to be looking for an element and the re-render happens during that process, which causes Cypress to get the original text value for that prefix.

As it happens, as well as moving from vue-cli to Vite, I'm also swapping usage of some helper functions I created to new command versions of the same things. Using the old helper functions, it works, and using basic Cypress built-in commands it also works, but with my own custom commands it doesn't.

I can import and `await nextTick()` from Vue, but then Cypress complains about using async functions and in most cases will actually error.

The "pure" version of the line (**which works fine**) is

```
cy.get('[data-test="login-view-username"] [data-test="form-input-prefix-text"]')
    .should('be.visible')
    .should('have.text', 'NARNIA \\');
```

My commands help me remember things a little better. These **fail when used to replace the above**, but **succeed if used directly afterwards to test the same thing** - so the commands themselves function, but there must be something about them or the way they're run that's different:

```
cy.findByData('login-view-username').findByData('form-input-prefix-text')
    .shouldBeVisible()
    .shouldHaveText('NARNIA \\');
```

For reference, the commands are defined as:

```
const findByData = (subject, testSelector, options) => {
    if (subject) {
        return cy.wrap(subject).find(`[data-test="${testSelector}"]`, options);
    }

    return cy.get(`[data-test="${testSelector}"]`, options);
};

export default {
    label: 'findByData',
    command: findByData,
    options: { prevSubject: ['optional', 'element'] },
};
```

```
const shouldBeVisible = subject => {
    return cy.wrap(subject).should('be.visible');
};

export default {
    label: 'shouldBeVisible',
    command: shouldBeVisible,
    options: { prevSubject: 'element' },
};
```

```
const shouldHaveText = (subject, text, trim = true) => {
    if (trim) {
        cy.wrap(subject).invoke('text').then($text => {
            expect($text.trim()).to.equal(text);

            return subject;
        });
    } else {
        cy.wrap(subject).should('have.text', text);
    }
};

export default {
    label: 'shouldHaveText',
    command: shouldHaveText,
    options: { prevSubject: 'element' },
};
```

Is there anything obvious about the setup of my commands that might cause this, or is there a way to safely await nextTick to avoid this issue?